# fastest way to communicate between two processes on Windows - java and python

Tags: python, java, windows, ipc, shared-memory

I have a java process that gets about 100B of data each 100ms from some other machine. I want to pass this 100B message to another process on the same machine which is written in python. After the python process processes this message I want to pass the processed message back to the java process. The processes run on Windows.
Is using shared memory the best way?

Comment: https://www.py4j.org/ is what you are looking for probably

Comment: Presumably, you don't care half as much about raw performance as you do about guaranteed response times. Using two languages and runtimes that neither have predictable performance characteristics isn't going to get you there.

Comment: @IInspectable Which response times exactly? The data that is received every 100ms is something that already happens.

Comment: @gold_cy Isn't it much slower than shared memory?

Comment: If the data arrives at a steady pace of 100 bytes/100 ms, then surely you wish to have that processed in a timely fashion. Non-deterministic garbage collection won't allow you to make any promises with respect to response times.

Comment: @RonyTesler https://www.py4j.org/about.html#alternatives-to-py4j

Comment: @IInspectable Do I need to synchronize the writes in one process with the reads from the other process, or the write operation is atomic?

Comment: Atomicity is a property of the implementation. Since you haven't decided on an implementation that question cannot be answered.

Comment: @IInspectable I thought maybe the operation system prevents it.